# Is it possible to get notified when an opened position has been modified?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4, forex, mql5

May I know how could I get notified in MQL4, if any of my placed or opened positions have been modified, due to getting [stop loss] or [take profit] or a pending order got triggered?

The reason is that I need to perform certain actions when my placed or opened positions are changed.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, it is, Sir.

One may opt to run an MQL4 code, that monitors the state of the set of both the placed and opened orders, as required above, and send you either an email or other message of your choice, whenever a monitored event happens to show up in the MetaTrader Terminal ( the Market events get reported into the Terminal from the Broker side as events ).

So feel free to use this approach to solving the expressed need. It is programmatically doable either using a Script or an ExpertAdvisor MQL4-code-execution functions. Can even go into distributed framework, if not willing to rely on MetaTrader platform constraints and implement just event-signalling and process the event externally, outside of the MQL4-code-base ( in C, C++, java, php, python, go, Erlang etc. depending on your preferences and performance / latency needs ).

Answer (score 1):

In mql5 - OnTradeTransaction() event, in mql4 it is not supported so need to keep everything in memory and loop over the open trades every tick/second/N milliseconds and compare current orders and their types with previous tick orders and notify if something has changed.